# Display map from python script?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, direction

I did a Network Analysis with ArcMap, executed by a python-script (I am building an ArcGIS-Tool).

In the very end, I want my **directions-output** to be shown as a **displayed map**, so the user can navigate with the map.

But right now I only get an HTML/XML/Text-File, which is nice, but not perfect.

```
# Process: Directions
arcpy.Directions_na(Route1__6_, "HTML", Directions2102_html, "Kilometers", "REPORT_TIME", "Minutes", "en", "NA Desktop", "")
```

Is there a way to display a map like ArcMap does, when I run the Network Analyst tool `Find Routes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Find Routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/find-routes.htm) tool outputs the directions feature class that you need. See Output_Directions_Name under the Syntax section in the documentation. Whatever you have named this direction feature class in your Python script contains the directions you want to add to a map.

You can use [AddLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addlayer.htm) to add the directions layer to the MXD

Comment: Yes, thanks, but is there a way to display the directions feature automatically from script?

Comment: Use acrpy.AddLayer. Link added to answer